# Can we controll L2 cache from C++ code?

Tags: c++, caching, boost

There were lots of videos/tutorials/talks this year on importance of vectors and arrays of object values that can be stored in cache. Yet I have not found any info  how to get assuarence that N vector elements from left/right from given posiotion are indeed loaded (not one but say at least 16)? Is  there any wrapper api in Boost or compiler specific predefined macros?

Comment: You don't manipulate the cache yourself. The cache is an "invisible" layer in front of your RAM. Any time you read from memory, it copies some amount of that memory into the cache under the assumption that you're likely to access a memory location nearby soon. The talks you've seen are recommending contiguous memory allocation, because then all the elements of an array/container can fit neatly into a cache line. That means you just need to use types like `std::vector` or `std::array`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://vimeo.com/m/97337258

This video will explain caches to you and what's happening as your program executes. It also teaches you how to best program to be cache friendly.

EDIT:

Basically, when you load in a variable that isn't already in cache, the CPU will load in a chunk of RAM around and including what you're using at the time, this loaded memory is the cache line. If you randomly use variables which aren't close together in RAM (a linked list for example) then one cache line is loaded for each time you go to the next node which takes time.

In a a data structure where the memory is stored sequentially ie. A vector or array. The data you're going to use next will most likely already be in the cache line and you don't have to leave the cpu cache to get the value

If you're iterating a sequential array then you're utilizing all of your cache line and also being prefretch friendly (the CPU will try and guess what memory you'll use next and if you're  iterating an sequential array, the CPU will prefetch the next cache line so the data you need will already be there before you ask for it.)

The size of a cache line can vary, but I believe its mainly 64 bytes and it depends on the CPU. Also all this is performed on the CPU without your program knowing. The compiler has no control over cache.

Comment: Link-only answers are not encouraged. If this link goes dead, the answer becomes worthless. Take the main points from the link and summarize them here.

Comment: It depends on the processor to prefetch, it'll look for pattens in how you access memory and try to load it before you need it. Youll probably have a cache miss when you go to the next array.

Comment: Answer to your question, there is no api or way to garentee it'll be in cache for you, but it's easy for you to program so it's likely it'll be cached, you juat have to have a predictable access patten and access memory which is close together to utilize a cache line.

Answer (score 0):

Different processors have different amounts of cache and different ways of managing it, and there may be other processes running concurrently with yours and competing for cache space, so you can't *guarantee* that data will be in cache at any particular time. The best you can do is arrange your data in RAM in a way that's conducive to caching.

When your data is contiguous, in an array or vector, then adjacent values will usually belong to the same cache line, so that when the processor fetches one value from RAM, it'll load some others into cache at the same time as a side effect. If your program uses those adjacent values soon afterward, they'll *probably* (no guarantee) still be in the cache.